# psmouse kernel module recompiling

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, kernel-modules

I have a ultrabook and its touchpad doesn't work.

```
Linux mike 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt25-1 (2016-03-06) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

touchpad doesn't work and it is also not listed in output of following command.

```
cat /proc/bus/input/devices
```

[it's output](https://gist.github.com/feyyazesat/9e04986aa7f2770d859d2c19ee82d769)

touchpad model : `"Sentelic Finger Sensing Pad Driver"`
so I typed following command

```
modinfo psmouse
```

[it's output](https://gist.github.com/feyyazesat/2a8671cee7e73d24b57d688269b84819)

according to these information when I type following command

```
ls /lib/modules/3.16.0-4-amd64/kernel/drivers/input/mouse/
```

I see following output :

```
appletouch.ko  bcm5974.ko  cyapa.ko  psmouse.ko  sermouse.ko  synaptics_i2c.ko  synaptics_usb.ko  vsxxxaa.ko
```

so as a result I thought I should recompile psmouse module which supports sentelic touchpad. I look around the internet, I get the linux repository.

I checked the tag `v3.16`

I went into `drivers/input/mouse` and I see following files

```
alps.c      appletouch.c  cyapa.c        elantech.c    hgpk.c    Kconfig     logibm.c     Makefile      pc110pad.c      pxa930_trkball.c  sentelic.h   synaptics.h      touchkit_ps2.c  trackpoint.h
alps.h      atarimouse.c  cypress_ps2.c  elantech.h    hgpk.h    lifebook.c  logips2pp.c  maplemouse.c  psmouse-base.c  rpcmouse.c        sermouse.c   synaptics_i2c.c  touchkit_ps2.h  vsxxxaa.c
amimouse.c  bcm5974.c     cypress_ps2.h  gpio_mouse.c  inport.c  lifebook.h  logips2pp.h  navpoint.c    psmouse.h       sentelic.c        synaptics.c  synaptics_usb.c  trackpoint.c
```

which includes `sentelic.h` and `sentelic.c` files also there is a Makefile but when I hit enter the command `make` it says `make: *** No targets.  Stop.`

my question is how could I compile `psmouse` module with the `sentelic touchpad support`.

**UPDATED :**

I get following information from windows driver's `fspad.inf` file

[driver](ftp://ftp.exper.com.tr/SURUCULER/NOTEBOOK/ULTRABOOK-ULTRANOTE/L4B-01/TPad_9.2.9.7.zip)

```
; Localizable Strings
Provider            = "Sentelic"
DiskId1             = "Finger Sensing Pad Driver Installation Disk"
AVC.DeviceDesc      = "Finger Sensing Pad"
AVC.DriverDisplayName = "Finger Sensing Pad Driver"
AVC.DriverDisplayVersion = "9.2.9.7"
AVC.DriverReleaseDate = "05/09/2012"
AVC.DriverCfg       = " "
fspad.SvcDesc       = "Finger Sensing Pad Driver for Windows 2000/XP/Vista/Win7"
fspadsvr.SvcDesc    = "Finger Sensing Control Service"
```

**UPDATED 2 :**

I tried following Live USBs and the result is same :

I checked `lsmod`, and `proc/bus/input/devices` not much different than details that I gave above. There is no touchpad thing.

```
Point Linux Mate Full 2.3-32 i386 Kernel  3.2.0-4
Ubuntu 12.04.4-Desktop amd64 Kernel 3.11
Xubuntu 16.04-Desktop amd64  Kernel 4.4.0
```

Is this a absolute kernel bug ? How could I be sure whether is this a bug or there is another solution, so according to that result I'm going to file a bug.

Comment: 1. Make and model of the Ultrabook? 2. « _My touchpad is "FSP blah blah."_ » Really?

Comment: Sentelic support should already be enabled in the Debian Jessie stock kernel.  Please could you post the output of `grep SENTELIC /boot/config-*` ?

Comment: @roaima the ultrabook is a product of turkey that because it is oem. there is dmidecode information on the following link https://gist.github.com/feyyazesat/605af917ee2a5d93206423d95959fab8

Comment: @JigglyNaga that is a great command, https://gist.github.com/feyyazesat/37a42e147adf2a86988f3413517013d0 in my version it looks yes there is. So now my problem is changed! I don't know where to go.

Comment: Did `lsmod` report that `psmouse` was loaded?  Do you see any error messages (including in `dmesg`) when you `modprobe psmouse`?

Comment: @JigglyNaga lsmod psmouse doesn't give any sign, but on my keyboard there is touchpad activate deactivate trigger with fn button. When I pressed it I checked dmesg there is something about it, it is absolutely a sign. https://gist.github.com/feyyazesat/8712269b2434ab582b8312ac7c3f8252 this is output from 2 different distribution. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XF2PErTAHhB0kOZxXRO2xyvwI7y1buH-pQ/view?usp=sharing photo is just my keyboard photo.

Comment: and I checked x0c3 is the 195 in decimal in xkmodmap it prints 195 out as keycode 195 = XF86Launch8 NoSymbol XF86Launch8 so the problem now how could I make this button activate the touchpad.

Comment: If `lsmod` output doesn't include `psmouse`, then the driver isn't loaded.  What happens when you `modprobe psmouse`?

Comment: after loading `psmouse` by `modprobe` I check `lsmod` so it gives me following output `psmouse                99249  0 ` no dmesg changes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40198/discussion-between-jigglynaga-and-fze).

Answer (score 1):

You can't (re)compile a kernel module by simply extracting the source and running `make` in its subdirectory.  Each distribution has a preferred method - in your case, see section [8.10. Compiling a Kernel](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.kernel-compilation.html) of the Debian handbook.

Specific drivers have to be enabled via the kernel's build configuration system.  You would need to enable `MOUSE_PS2_SENTELIC`.  However, as that is already enabled in your kernel, rebuilding isn't necessary here.

If, after `modprobe psmouse`, there are no helpful error messages and you still don't see anything in `/proc/bus/input/devices`, then it's possible that the device isn't recognised/supported by the current linux driver.  You might be able to find more details on the [driver development site](https://github.com/saaros/sentelic/), but that hasn't had much activity since the driver was included in the kernel.

Comment: thanks for your answer I will mark best answer after changing my question and getting a proper idea, recompiling idea and my approach was my total ignorance. I ask you could you please give me an idea how to properly debug my partial problem. My problem is there is no sign about my touchpad in my system. But in windows everything is properly OK. I can give you any details if you would desire. Could you please ?

Comment: If that is help ftp://ftp.exper.com.tr/SURUCULER/NOTEBOOK/ULTRABOOK-ULTRANOTE/L4B-01/TPad_9.2.9.7.zip following windows program is my touchpad driver

Comment: I updated my question and added several information from windows driver.